# How to handle tab change event in coolite tab panel?

Tags: tabpanel

I am working with a coolite tabpanel. I want to handle the tab change event from client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listeners: {
        'tabchange': function(tabPanel, tab){
            // Ignore tab1 since it is a separate tab panel and we're managing history for it also.
            // We'll use its handler instead in that case so we don't get duplicate nav events for sub tabs.
            if(tab.id != 'tab1'){
                Ext.History.add(tabPanel.id + tokenDelimiter + tab.id);
            }
        }
    }
```